# How mysql implement mysql_use_result?

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

In my project, I would like to fetch millions of records into client, then I find the memory used in client side is pretty huge(about 1.5G+). Then I find using `SSCursor` of Mysql would decrease the memory that client use. 
I have made an experiments using `SSCursor`, I found that the memory used by client is pretty small , and the memory used by server is also vary too much. So, I am curious how mysql implement `mysql_use_result`.

Comment: Which part of the description in the MySQL Reference Manual are you not understanding?  [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-use-result.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-use-result.html)

Comment: I understand the manual, but it doesn't mention how the server response to `mysql_fetch_row()`, does the server just store the result when the first fetch in memory or in a temporary table or something else?

Comment: What's the source of the data: eg an XML file, a CSV file, a SQL dump file, another database, etc?  Be aware that the old mysql_* extension which you're using is deprecated in version 5.5 of PHP (the current version) and is being removed from version 7 (the next version). You need migrate over to using either the mysqli_* extension or PDO

Comment: There are millions of records in a Mysql table, and I would like to fetch them using `SSDictCursor` of Python MySQLdb library. And I am wondering whether the Mysql Server would consume 1.5GB memory instead of client which may influence other applications using this Mysql server.